# Python function to check string for non-matching vowels

Tags: python

I want to write a function in python that takes in a string and checks to see if all of the vowels are the same letter (true) or not (false). I got pretty close but I'm hung up trying to figure out how to make it only return one verdict for the string instead of comparing all subsequent pairs of vowels.

Here is my code

```
def checkvowels(str) :
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    last_vowel = None
    for c in str: 
        if c in vowels and last_vowel == None:
            last_vowel = c
        elif last_vowel != None:
            if c != last_vowel:
                print('False')
                return
            else:
                print('True')
```

so right now

```
checkvowels('tree climber')
```

returns

```
TRUE
FALSE
```

instead of just FALSE. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want only one result reported, then you have to forestall printing until you're done.  You cannot have `print` statements *inside* the loop.

```
def checkvowels(str) :
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    last_vowel = None

    result = True
    for c in str: 
        if c in vowels and last_vowel == None:
            last_vowel = c
        elif last_vowel != None:
            if c != last_vowel:
                result = False

    print(result)
```

Even easier to follow, let's try this more in line with how you describe the problem:

1. Extract all of the vowels.

Code:

```
found_vowels = [c for c in str if c in vowels]
```

2. count how many different vowels you found: make a set (to remove duplicates) and see how many elements are in the list:

Code:

```
vowel_count = len(set(found_vowels)
print(vowel_count == 1)
```

This gives you either `True` or `False`, as desired.  In its short form:

```
def checkvowels(phrase) :
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    print(len(set([c for c in phrase if c in vowels])) == 1)
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you. It seems that spaces cause your first example to return False, can you help me understand why that is?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a running solution with set - a set in python can only have one entry for each added element:

```
# I simply compare if in my set_of_seen_vowels are more than one vowel entry 

def checkvowels(string) :
    vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
    last_vowel = None
    set_of_seen_vowels = set()
    for c in string: 
        if c in vowels:
            set_of_seen_vowels.add(c)
 
    print(set_of_seen_vowels)
    if len(set_of_seen_vowels) != 1:
        print('False')
        return False
    else:
        print('True')
        return True
```

Also be aware `str` is a keyword in python and shouldn't be used as a variable name.